# JQuery spinner for time

Tags: jquery, spinner, javascript-globalize

I would like to use the jquery spinner to display the time.
In their example http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time  they use globalize.js. I am not sure where from to take this file from.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

CDN *(Content Delivery Network)* are one of the ways to take the file or use the file reference as `src` of script. Some of the popular networks are:

1. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/globalize
2. http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn#Globalize_Releases_on_the_CDN_12
3. http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/globalize

Take this library from [CDN. Just choose your choice of library from here.](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/globalize)

---

If you have nodejs installed then you can use that to load that module globally/locally. Use this command:

```
npm install globalize //<----this command will install this file locally
npm install globalize -g // -g flag will install it globally in the installed node modules.
```

Comment: how about the globalize.culture.de-DE.js (in my case fr-FR) that they use in the example?